# How to hard delete data when setting NULL in database row

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle database with table "A".

The table has a column "SensitiveValue" (a string of a defined length).

At some point I need to set the data in "SensitiveValue" field to NULL. However I need to be sure that when setting to NULL, the data in that cell will be 100% completely erased and can't be recovered even on physical level by inspecting the hard disk.

Can anyone point me to some solutions how to achieve this with Oracle database or any other database type where you have seen similar problem?

I tried searching the docs but couldn't find anything related.

One way, as I think, could be to completely overwrite the row value with some preset dummy value that matches the length of the column so it actually replaces the physical data. However this introduces complexity of dealing with this special value instead of a NULL which is more standard.

Comment: If you start the question with "I have an Oracle database"... then why are you tagging other databases ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie, if he moves the data from oracle to sql server after setting the value, it will solve his issue

Comment: One thing to consider is that any transaction you run will write into the transaction logs.   So it might not be as simple as what happens in the database block.   Probably not an oracle question, its a question for the filesystem Oracle is installed on.

Comment: There are some solutions that don't scale great [like using a child table for each row, which can just be dropped when needed].   This avoids the transaction log issue [drops aren't in transactions].   All those tables get put on their own tablespace, which is on a device that meets your security requirements [whatever they are].   File under "better than nothing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any software-based solution that gives a 100% guarantee of secure deletion. Some solutions may be good enough for certain purposes, but if you require the data to be irrecoverable, this is not a programming task. I would vote to close this question as "not programming related" but I think it's programming related to understand why certain tasks cannot be solved with programming.

In an MVCC database, pages are copied instead of overwritten in place. The copies will probably be stored on a different location on the physical media. The old row versions are deleted eventually, when they are no longer needed.

Different brands of RDBMS implement [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) differently, but many of them are similar in that they make copies of data.

In the case of Oracle, here's some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-D081389D-C338-4E74-BF64-6524795EF764) that applies to Oracle 19:

> Whenever a user modifies data, Oracle Database creates undo entries, which it writes to undo segments. The undo segments contain the old values of data that have been changed by uncommitted or recently committed transactions. Thus, multiple versions of the same data, all at different points in time, can exist in the database.

But the space once used by the old row version won't necessarily be overwritten at any predictable time. So the bits could remain there indefinitely, in theory. Someone who recovered the physical drive could still access them.

Some companies do destructive erasing of physical drives when they are taken out of service. But this is not effective for some types of SSD devices. Cf. [https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//~swanson/papers/Fast2011SecErase.pdf](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//%7Eswanson/papers/Fast2011SecErase.pdf)

At my last job, we stored data about financial transactions. It was full of sensitive data and personally identifiable information. Old SSD drives had to be physically shredded when they were taken out of service. Even when a drive was still working, we had strict policies about not reusing them on database servers with a lower security level.

Also keep in mind sensitive values are recorded in transaction logs, query logs, and backups. If any sensitive values are presented in the user interface of your application, someone could save that at the client end, or screenshot it, or simply take a photo of their display. If you need a strategy to implement 100% secure erase, you must account for the full life cycle of the data, and every place it might have been stored or viewed.

Comment: Excuse me, but - what did you mean to say when posting link "for a description of how this is implemented in Oracle"?

Comment: I meant someone who is interested in more details can click the link I provided. The OP's question is tagged for Oracle, so I found a documentation page specifically about Oracle's implementation of snapshots.

Comment: Right; however, that's not how Oracle implemented it. Link points to a document located on Oracle site, but it is related to Berkeley DB (acquired by Oracle corporation in 2006).

Comment: Woops! Thank you for that correction. I've removed the incorrect link, and edited to make a general statement about MVCC and a link to Oracle 19 documentation.

Comment: No problem :) Nice reading, BTW! Your answer, I mean - not documentation :)

Comment: Since a simple overwrite of data can't be trusted to obscure previous content (it typically takes *several* overwrites to be "safe"), most systems with this kind of concern would encrypt all data at rest on the disk. This largely eliminates the need to ensure overwrites. Oracle has built-in options for this, as do most operating systems.